# In Roblox Studio, how can I make an event fire when a VR controller's trigger is pressed? (Oculus Quest 2)

Tags: lua, virtual-reality, roblox

I'm trying to make it so that you can pick up and drop objects using the bottom triggers of the Oculus Quest 2 controllers instead of simply making them Nexus VR tools. How can I make something happen when I press a trigger in Roblox VR? They don't have key codes, and I can't find any APIs in VR Service that fire events related to buttons being pushed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use Roblox Lua's `UserInputService` to listen for when a button was pressed, then use `<input>.KeyCode` to find the actual button that was pressed

You could then use an if statement to check if the button they pressed ties to a certain function, then call your event/function inside the if statement

Comment: That's what I did. I pressed the controller triggers, and I asked it to print the input's keycode. The output was just "InputObject".

Comment: Try using <UserInputService>:IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.<Key>) to find if the key they pressed ties to a certain function. Here is a link for further reading on :IsKeyDown() https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/UserInputService/IsKeyDown